# powershell ip address csv file

Tags: csv, powershell, networking, ip

I am trying to dump the contents of only the live adapters to a csv file, for later importing.

The issue was the usage of $_. below.

```
$colNicConfigs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where { $_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE" }

#loop over each adapter
foreach ($objNicConfig in $colNicConfigs) 
{ 
$objnic=Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | where {$_.deviceID -eq "$objNicConfig.Index" }
#$strname=$objnicconfig.description.split(":")[0]
#replace strname above when testing against actual server since no dot1q defined on my wks
$strname="MGMT:Something"
$connid=$_.NetworkConnectionID
$ipaddr=$_.IPAddress(0)
$ipsm=$_.IPSubnet(0)
$dg=$_.DefaultIPGateway

}
# create dictionary entries
$report = @()
$report += New-Object psobject -Property @{Name=$strname;ConnID=$connid;IP=$ipaddr;SM=$ipsm;DG=$dg}
$report | export-csv .\nic.csv
```

Comment: What part is failing? What error are you getting? Put it in PowerGUI script editor or ISE and debug through line by line.

Comment: Explaining specifically what is not working will help you get a better answer. Right off the bat though I suspect that you want to use $objNic instead of $_ to get information about the NIC and [] is the array indexer in PS not ()

Answer (score 1):

Your initial issues are the use of "$underscore" within your `foreach` loop. If you want to reference properties of the `$objNicConfig` you will use that in place of the "$underscore". So instead of `$connid=$_.networkConnectionID` you would use `$connid=$objNicConfig.networkConnectionID`

Also `IpAddress and IPSubnet` are not methods they are properties, so dropping the (0) will return the write info. If your NIC has multiple IPs I cannot attest to how this will display as my machine does not, that I'm testing on.

Other things I see is that you will need to nest another `foreach` loop in there in order to reference both WMI namespaces...so something like:

```
$colNicConfigs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where { $_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE" }

foreach ($objNicConfig in $colNicConfigs) 
{
    foreach($objnic in (gwmi win32_networkadapter | where {$_.DeviceID -eq $objNicConfig.Index}))
    {
        $strName = "MGMT:Something"
        $objNicConfig.NetworkConnectionID
        $objNicConfig.IpAddress
        $objNic.IPSubnet
        $objNicConfig.DefaultIPGateway
    }
}
```

The above code is what I used to return info on the NICs of my computer.

Now with the "dictionary entries" section. You will not be able to reference the variables within your `foreach` loop in the manner of adding a `psobject`. You are only going to capture the last one found within the `foreach` loop code. If you want to first collect the information in your `foreach` loop and then use it later down in your script I would suggest looking at `hash tables` for this.